# How do I open the GWT samples in eclipse Helios and GWT 2.1.1?

Tags: eclipse, gwt, sample

What is the straight-forward way of importing one of the [GWT samples](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/downloads/list?can=2&q=tutorial&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+ReleaseDate+Size+DownloadCount) in eclipse Helios + GWT 2.1.1. It seems like the content of the zip file doesn't contain any project files for eclipse.

I tried the following:

- create a GWT project 'bla'
- Delete the src ad war folder and
  replace it with the src and war
  folder from the sample
- refresh the project in eclipse
- hit 'run'

> [ERROR] Unable to find
>   'bla/bla.gwt.xml' on
>   your classpath; could be a typo, or
>   maybe you forgot to include a
>   classpath entry for source?

So I go to the run configuration and remove the path for the example projects from the arguments list. I also changed the name of hosted html page to the one in the sample. Hit 'run' and:

> [ERROR] Invalid version number "2.0"
>   passed to external.gwtOnLoad(),
>   expected "2.1"; your hosted mode
>   bootstrap file may be out of date;

Now I need an out of date version of GWT to run these samples? What is going on, I just want to look at a sample to learn a new concept.

Comment: Actually it says that you have GWT 2.0 but sample is for 2.1 version of GWT.

Comment: Added another answer about your error message.

Comment: I have no other than GWT 2.1.1 installed (this is a clean install of eclipse + GWT from two days ago)

Answer (score 2):

Reading the readme.txt in the GWT samples directory I came across a solution that works on Eclipse 3.7. Assuming you have ant installed on your machine, execute the following from the sample's directory:

> ant eclipse.generate

This will generate both the .classpath and .project files needed to import the sample into Eclipse and run it.

Here the relevant excerpt from README.txt:

> -- Option A: Import your project into Eclipse (recommended) --
>
> If you use Eclipse, you can simply import the generated project into
>   Eclipse. We've tested against Eclipse 3.4 and 3.5.  Later versions
>   will likely also work, earlier versions may not.
>
> If the directory containing this file does not have a .classpath or
>   .project file, generate them by running 'ant eclipse.generate'
>
> In Eclipse, go to the File menu and choose:
>
> File -> Import... -> Existing Projects into Workspace
>
> Browse to the directory containing this file,   select "Mail".
>        Be sure to uncheck "Copy projects into workspace" if it is checked.
>        Click Finish.    You can now browse the project in Eclipse.
>
> To launch your web app in GWT development mode, go to the Run menu and
>   choose:
>
> Run -> Open Debug Dialog...
>
> Under Java Application, you should find a launch configuration
>   named "Mail".  Select and click "Debug".
>
> You can now use the built-in debugger to debug your web app in
>   development mode.

In eclipse 3.7, instead of Run -> Open Debug Dialog..., its Run -> Debug Configurations. I got both the showcase and mail samples running following those commands. Should work for all of the other samples as well.

Answer (score 1):

The examples that come with GWT SDK were built in different ways.  Some are Maven builds, others use Ant.  Eclipse can handle these common builds directly, but you have to choose the right option.

So, if you want to open the Expenses project in eclipse, you would look in the projects root directory (i.e. ../gwt2.4/samples/Expenses) where you'll find a file called ***pom.xml***.  That is a Maven build file.  To import it into your Work space select:

1. File->Import...
2. Open Maven->Existing Maven Projects, and click on Next > button
3. Browse your file system til you reach the Expenses folder. Click  on it and Select OK.

At this point it will show you the Projects in that directory in the Projects: area of the window...only one in this case:  /pom.xml com.google.gwt.sample.expenses:...etc.

- click on the checkbox for that project, Next>
- Finally, it ask you to map plugins.  You'll need to select in the drop down menu under Actions the required plugins (such as m2e).

In other project folders you may find a ***build.xml*** file instead.  That's an Ant build file.  To import that you do something similar, *but different* (of course!):

1. File->New->Project...
2. Open the Java folder and select "Java Project from Existing Ant Buildfile", Next >
3. Click the Browse button, dig through your directory to the project folder and select the build.xml file, and Open it.
4. Project name should fill in automatically, just select the declaration to use in the middle window and click Finish.

Answer (score 0):

Since those tutorial only include the src and war directory, the idea remains to:

- create a new project following [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/GWT/article.html)
- remove any created class part of the example files which are automatically added (see [Issue 1547](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1547))

> Unfortunately the Google Plugin does not allow to created a new Web Application Project without creating template files. The template files are nice for the first try but annoying if you want to start from scratch with a new GWT application.

[image]

- copy the src and war directory in place within the now empty project

Answer (score 0):

Following your [ticket 5847](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5847) (No easy and straight-forward way to make examples work in eclipse),

- as [xo4yhamope](https://stackoverflow.com/users/425491/xo4yhamope) comments, you need the right GWT option.
- and did you consider the [Issue 5038](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5038) about the error message:

  Unable to find 'xxxx.gwt.xml' on your classpath;
  could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?

> > This message usually means you attempted to refresh the browser before dev mode has had a chance to finish loading the module.
> >     The uppercase/lowercase confusion happens because the module has been renamed to 'stockwatcher', but dev mode cannot map 'stockwatcher' to "StockWatcher' until it has finished loading the entire module.
>
> So, it's just a matter of waiting a few seconds longer after the Development Mode pane says I should go to http://127.0.0.1:8888/StockWatcher.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 ?
>
> That seems a little messed up. It should wait until it's actually ready before telling me it's ok, because users (like me) are going to go there as soon as the UI says it's ready.
>
> The other confusing part is that the server begins serving the host page as soon as that message in the UI comes up. Because this was happening, I assumed that the server was completely up, even though (as it turns out) it wasn't.
>
> Anyway, waiting a few more seconds seems to resolve the "`Unable to find 'stockwatcher.gwt.xml' on your classpath`" problem. Thanks!

Comment: `GWT SDK[GWT - 2.1.1]` is the only SDK I have installed. And the first error is resolved by changing the run configuration. Since I deleted the package 'bla' and replaced it with the sample it didn't show up in the classpath. So I removed it from the arguments in the run configuration. I don't know if that's the way to do it but it seemed to bring me further. Did you actually manage to run one of these samples?

Comment: @Jan: no, I haven't directly used those examples. I just tried to list some of the errors I can think of. Considering those examples might be a bit older than 2.1.1, did you try older version of GWT to see (like just 2.1, or even 2.0 for 2.0 examples) to check if there isn't some kind of regression introduced with the latest GWT?

Comment: Do you mind trying? I don't have a lot experience in eclipse or GWT and I suspect I am doing something stupid, perhaps you find something? For now I am going to wait a few days for response on the issue report (and read the manuals). I must say I am a bit disappointed in google. Normally, their products work right out of the box. I thought it was easy to just export a project in eclipse. Why didn't they do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm beginning to suspect this is a bug in the samples. I am adding this answer so it can be marked as an answer when I get confirmation about that.

I was trying out some other samples and came across [this page](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/i18n.html). At the top is a little explanation for how to download and import the sample.

> ### Before you begin
>
> **The StockWatcher project**
>
> This tutorial builds on the GWT
>   concepts and the StockWatcher
>   application created in the [Build a
>   Sample GWT Application](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/gettingstarted.html) tutorial.
>   If you have not completed the Build a
>   Sample GWT Application tutorial and
>   are familiar with basic GWT concepts,
>   you can import the StockWatcher
>   project as coded to this point.
>
> 1. Download the [StockWatcher project](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/downloads/detail?name=Tutorial-GettingStarted-2.1.zip).
> 2. Unzip the file.
> 3. Import the project into Eclipse
>
>    1. From the `File` menu, select the `Import...` menu option.
>    2. Select the import source General > Existing Projects into
>         Workspace. Click the `Next` button.
>    3. For the root directory, browse to and select the StockWatcher
>         directory (from the unzipped file).
>         Click the `Finish` button.
>
> If you are using ant, edit the
>   `gwt.sdk` property in
>   StockWatcher/build.xml to point to
>   where you unzipped GWT.

Now this is what I call straight-forward and easy.

At that point I had already built the StockWatcher in a previous tutorial but I got intrigued by the fact that it was explained exactly as I tried it the first time. So I downloaded the project and it had the correct eclipse project structure. I tried to import it 'et voila' I have the project in eclipse. I runs out of the box (with warnings). That is how expected the samples to be.

This experience leads me into thinking that the sample projects are malformed (as eclipse projects) and need to be updated. Let's hope my [issue repor](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5847)t leads to results.

Answer (score 0):

-- Option A: Import your project into Eclipse (recommended) --

If you use Eclipse, you can simply import the generated project into Eclipse.
We've tested against Eclipse 3.4 and 3.5.  Later versions will likely also
work, earlier versions may not.

If the directory containing this file does not have a .classpath or .project
file, generate them by running 'ant eclipse.generate'

In Eclipse, go to the File menu and choose:

File -> Import... -> Existing Projects into Workspace

Browse to the directory containing this file,
  select "Mail".

Be sure to uncheck "Copy projects into workspace" if it is checked.

Click Finish.

You can now browse the project in Eclipse.

Copy from readme.txt supplied by samples. I tried this method, it's OK.

Answer (score 0):

To import GWT showcase(2.5.1) I did following steps:

1. Create a new Google Web Application Project

   New –> Other –> Google –> Web Application Project
2. Provide the project name “Showcase” and the Package name is com.google.gwt.sample.showcase
3. Click Finish
4. Go to eclipse plugin folder and traverse to the gwt
5. Under that folder go to gwt-2.3.\samples\Showcase
6. Copy (Ctrl C) all the contents. The contents are
   a. src
   b. test
   c. war
   d. build.xml
   e. README.txt
7. In the eclipse, right click on the Showcase project and paste. Overwrite all the files
8. The files should start copying without any problem
9. Right click on the Showcase and Run As “Web Application”
10. You should have your Showcase working like Gem!

For me it worked like a charm ;)

Ref : http://simplestepswebdev.wordpress.com/2011/05/16/import-gwt-samples-into-eclipse/